# Я пытаюсь заполнить массив русскими буквами, но компьютер отказывается воспринимать это

Tags: c++

```
 for (i = 'А'; i <= 'Я'; i++)
  grid_ru[r][c++] = i;
```

(Используется многомерный массив), перед этим соответственно прописал:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Не правильно выполняется целый кусок программы из-за этого. Если знаете в чём проблема - отпишитесь пожалуйста!
[полный код](https://pastebin.com/YNHbZaWn)

Comment: Коды русских букв в cp1251 больше 127, соответственно при преобразовании в знаковое целое (ваша переменная `i`) они становятся отрицательными. Используйте в своем коде для таких целей `unsigned i`

Comment: @avp теперь не пускает в момент проверки условия (479 строчка) Ошибка: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

Comment: Берите отладчик и смотрите, я ваш код отлаживать не буду

Comment: любопытно что вы хотели сделать с массивом строк, написав ~500 страниц  кода,  с многочисленными сравнениями, но такой труд  не могу не уважать...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 500 строк* шифровка и дешифровка сообщения с выбором языка для шифровки. Как раз во время шифровки и проверки некого условия возникает ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы просто не сделать массив статичным?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* ru_lower_alph = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    const char* ru_upper_alph = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    const char* en_lower_alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const char* en_upper_alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    printf(ru_lower_alph);
    printf(ru_upper_alph);
    printf(en_lower_alph);
    printf(en_upper_alph);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ на С. Вопрос был задан с меткой С++. если вы не чуете разницы - пичалька

Comment: @Andrey в данном случае есть разница?